# How to monitor PHP-FPM in zabbix?

Tags: php, monitoring, zabbix

I want to monitor PHP-FPM in Zabbix. Tell me, please, how to do it?

Are there any templates to try it ?

Comment: What do you want to monitor? How would you obtain that data without Zabbix, using scripts or any other method?

Comment: I am going to use scripts

Comment: I mean are there any templates to make my work easier?

Comment: There are some, like https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/tree/master/php-fpm , but that is rather basic question then :)

Comment: OK then, posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some, like https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/tree/master/php-fpm .

Looking at https://github.com/jizhang/zabbix-templates/blob/master/php-fpm/php-fpm-check.sh , it parses the status page. In case of errors, arbitrary negative values are used.